# Toast message won't popup on button click

Tags: php, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is the code, all I want to do is to test if user credentials are  entered in the database then display success via *toast* message if they are and if they are not to return an error message.

Here is what I have found out from one of the websites I followed all the instructions and ended up with the code below but the toast still doesn't show up.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Org.Json;
using System.Text;
namespace App
{
    [Activity(Label = "App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity, Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener
    {
        EditText username, password;
        Button signIn;
        signInAsync sn;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            initialize();
        }
        public void initialize()
        {
            username = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText1);
            password = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText2);
            signIn = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button1);
            signIn.SetOnClickListener(this);
        }
        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            EditText username = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText1);
            EditText password = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText2);
            //Cisti fokus
            username.ClearFocus();
            password.ClearFocus();
            //imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(username.WindowToken, 0);
            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
            //Sklanja tastaturu s ekrana na klik na pozadinu.
        }
        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            switch (v.Id)
            {
                case Resource.Id.button1:
                    sn = new signInAsync(this);
                    sn.Execute();
                    break;
            }
        }
        public class signInAsync : AsyncTask
        {
            MainActivity mainActivity;

            public signInAsync(MainActivity mainActivity)
            {
                this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
            }
            string username, password;
            protected override void OnPreExecute()
            {
                base.OnPreExecute();

                username = mainActivity.username.Text;
                password = mainActivity.password.Text;
            }
            protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)
            {

                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                client.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                Uri uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.198/android/login.php");
                NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
                parameters.Add("username", username);
                parameters.Add("password", password);
                var response = client.UploadValues(uri, parameters);
                var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(responseString);
                if (ob.OptString("success").Equals("1"))
                {
                    mainActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(mainActivity, "Uspješno ste se ulogovali", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    });
                };
                if (ob.OptString("error").Equals("2"))
                    Toast.MakeText(mainActivity, "Pogresno", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                if (ob.OptString("error").Equals("3"))
                    Toast.MakeText(mainActivity, "Error", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$db_name = "korisnici";
$mysql_username = "Mpro";
$mysql_password = "prolinet";
$server_name = "192.168.1.198";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);

if($conn) {
    echo "Connection success";
} else {
    echo "Faliure to connect";
}

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $user_name = $_POST['username'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['password'];
    $mysql_qry = "SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE username = '$user_name' AND password = '$user_pass'";
    if(mysql_fetch_row($mysql_qry)){
        $response["success"] = 1;
        echo json_encode($response);

    } else{
        $response["error"]=2;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

} else {
    $response["error"] = 3;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I am sorry to bother you but I am a Xamarin beginner.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
Toast.MakeText(mainActivity, "Uspješno ste se ulogovali", ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

with:

```
Toast.MakeText(mainActivity.this, "Uspješno ste se ulogovali", ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: if this helps. Please mark this as correct answer so others getting help from this

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work but thank you. I get 2 errors after I change to .this Identifier expected and "," expected.

Comment: @SWALLOW please check my updated answer. and if you getting some error feel free to ask and share your logcat so we can help you further

Comment: By the way above code is belongs to xamarin not native android.

Comment: I am giving you code for native android. you want for xamarin?

Comment: Yes sir please do.

Comment: you having some error? If yes post your logcat please. because Toast code is correct

Comment: I am not having a traditional error it is just when I try to debug an app live on my device. When I enter username and password that I stored on wamp and click login I don't get confromation for correct username and password or one of the errors.

Comment: please try to check your service with URL and then apply that in android if that service is correctly return values in URL. From this you can get that is any error is there in Service/Api or in Android side

Comment: Run your Service/Api on browser with static values. Hope you understand

Comment: Here is what I get when I run url from my browser http://pasteboard.co/3EXQxLAZt.png  . As you can see the php file gives me correct error '3' witch means that there is not username or password set in edittext.

Comment: So you getting value JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(responseString); here in ob? please debug and check once

Comment: if (ob.OptString("success").Equals("1")) i think the problem is here. when you getting error from URL you cant get ob.OptString("success"). So for this you need to pass same parameter. Hope you understand this @SWALLOW

Answer (score 0):

If you want show toast on success or failure while using asyntask use toast in onPostExcute() method of asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure the line for showing toast is executed.
you can use Log class to print some message to ensure what is happening in your application.

Answer (score 0):

use `getContext` or `mainActivity.this` instead of `mainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot be sure that your activity is in a valid state from the background thread. So rather than passing in the activity pass in the application context like so:

```
public signInAsync(Context appContext)
```

And then do:

```
Toast.MakeText(appContext,...
```

So when you call signInAsync from an activity you will call it like this:

```
signInAsync(this.ApplicationContext)
```